# subprocess object has not attribute 'call'

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I am trying to use subprocess module for one of my script.
When I run the following simple code:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(["dir"], shell=True)
```

I get the following error;

> AttributeError: 'module' object has not attribute

I use Python 2.7 version. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I hope today you learned why you should *never* name files with the same name of existing modules (e.g. `subprocess.py`, or having a package `subprocess/__init__.py`); the same holds true for built-in functions and classes (so avoid: `list = [1,2,3]` because you end up shadowing the built-in `list` class).

Comment: I suggest in an answer not to do this by posting functional proper code and I get downvotes. nice, people from stackoverflow.

Comment: @Roxanne Unfortunately your answer was wrong and would not solve the problem.

Comment: Hi @DanielRoseman, subprocess module was working fine yesterday. Unfortunately it gives me that  attribute error today. Any ideas ? Thanks

Comment: @yakupme as Bakuriu suggests, you have a local file called subprocess.py; you should rename it.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thanks a lot ;)